# Should I connect the white wire to the aux connection on my new thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I changed my old thermostat to a honeywell rth3100c. I was instructed to attach the white wire to the aux. connection. I do not have a heat pump. all electric system. Is this correct and if so for heat do I set it to heat or aux heat? In the settings I chose electric furnace for both functions

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of the existing wiring, and information on how it was connected to the old thermostat, would be helpful.

Comment: Was your old thermostat a heat pump thermostat?  How did you determine the rth3100c was the correct thermostat to buy for your system?  Do you know which wire's were connected where on the old stat?

Comment: Wire colors are not standardized so it's impossible to say based on color alone. We'd need to know what what terminals each wire was connected to on the old thermostat, and/or what they are currently connected to on the furnace control board.